# Name is undefined. Post Request Nodejs

Tags: node.js, postman, body-parser

Problem is it was working fine with another project but in this it's not. I have tried adding all the possible headers but all in vein.

**Schema:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const products = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    manufacturer: String
});

const Product = mongoose.model('Products', products);
module.exports = Product;
```

**Post Request:**

```
router.post('/api/products/', (req, res, next) => {

    const product = new Product({
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price,
        manufacturer: req.body.manufacturer
    });
    product
        .save()
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.status(200).json({ message: result });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.status(500).json({ error: error });
        })

    next();
});
```

**Headers:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();
const Product = require('../Models/products');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Even with every possible header, the `name` is `undefined`.

Screenshot Attached.

Maybe postman is obsessed with lays.

[image]

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const morgan = require('morgan')
const orders = require('./Routes/products');
app.use(orders);
app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

```
const port = process.env.port || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Connected ");
})

mongoose
    .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => console.log("Connected to Compass"))
    .catch((err) => console.error("error found...", err));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error('Address Not Found');
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
})
```

Comment: Have you tried logging request's body before passing it to the `Product`? To check whether your post request is even working or not. Check if the body contains a name variable?

Comment: the request is working but the body is undefined.

Comment: Why did you set extended as false? It helps in parsing with QS and works.

Comment: it's not working.

Comment: @Sarah it's difficult to identify the root cause (of which there could be a few) because you haven't included a number of important points e.g. the sample request coming from POSTMAN (in its raw form) and the route config (where does it happen?). Either your request is not valid or your route is being hooked up before the middleware is, it's a fairly common issue.

Comment: @James I have added the remaining portion in the end from the main file.

Comment: @James why are people giving me negatives for a question they can't solve?

Comment: @Sarah so it's looking more and more like as suspected, ensure you hook up your Router _after_ your bodyParser middleware. Negative votes on here are indicative of many things, unless the downvoter comments it can be hard to say for sure. However, people sometimes downvote if they have seen the question many times or there isn't enough information in the question (which, unfortunately, this one ticks both of those). But you are improving it with advice so hopefully the downvotes get removed (I've just taken one off for you :))

Comment: @James thank you.  I know the problem. it lies in the route

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the `extended` property to **true**.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```